# Git : git clone with Bit bucket repository throwing fatal error

Tags: git, github, bitbucket, git-clone

I am trying to clone my bit bucket  repository to local by `git clone` command

Facing following Error :-

```
fatal: unable to access 'https://username@bitbucket.org/myrep/movieplace.git/': 
Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 1080: Timed out
```

I did not faced this type of error while `cloning` `fetching` `committing` with `git`.

Honesty speaking guyz  when i `refreshed` my `windows-8` PC the above error started.

How could i get rid of this problem ?

Comment: Check if bb is up. I sort of remember of an scheduled maintenance.

Comment: @xvan i did that dude but no use .. trying to find some solution ..

Answer (score 0):

This page states that you are trying to connect to bitbucket using a bad URL format:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/use-the-ssh-protocol-with-bitbucket-cloud-221449711.html

You are trying to connect to:

```
https://username@bitbucket.org/myrep/movieplace.git/
```

When you should be connecting to (using replacements of course):

```
https://<accountname>@bitbucket.org/<accountname>/<reponame>.git
```

You should also be using port 443 instead of 1080